# Connect Oracle Database FROM SSIS Package SQL Server

Tags: oracle, ssis, attunity

I am using the Microsoft Connector for Oracle by Attunity with SQL Server 2010 Integration Services. Install the Microsoft Connector for Oracle by Attunity.SSIS Package connected succeed oracle connection manager editor.

First of all create one database on sqlserver. Example (ordb Database).

Start->All Program->Click SQL Server Data Tools and then click New Project & Select the Integration Project click Ok Button.

Drag the Data flow Task from SSIS ToolBox in Control Flow. Select the data flow task and right click edit , open data flow.

In dataflow  under Oracle Source drag the ssis toolbox and create new for connection manager: xx and choose the Data Access Code :Table Name& name of the table or view : Dar.xx.

Select Table od table on Oracle Source and od table totally three columns there (Id,Name,Xml). Once dataflow path connect with oledb destination xml column hidden and remaining two columns only there in preview.

Another xy Table one column there (Xml Column). In the oracle source created connection manager and selected xx table.

I will connect Dataflow path editor to another oledb destination in ssis toolbox. Once connect dataflow path editor and open oledb destination but (This Component has no available input columns) aler box shows.

How to fix the issue from ssis package

Comment: Did you try changing the destination...give a try to `File File Destination`. Also are you using `oledb source` or `Attunity Source`?